# maven profile uses wrong property in build

Tags: maven, properties, profile

i have a pom file that generates a .war and i want to use 2 different profiles: ots and wiblatt

each of those profiles has a property (with the same name), which is used in jboss-web.xml: mailabo.ear

the two profiles look like this

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ots</id>
        <properties>
            <mailabo.ear>mailabo-ots-ear-${project.version}</mailabo.ear>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ots</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>ots</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>wiblatt</id>
        <properties>
            <mailabo.ear>mailabo-wiblatt-ear-${project.version}</mailabo.ear>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>wiblatt</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>wiblatt</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

this works fine:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -P ots => mailabo-web-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT-ots.war
where ${mailabo.ear} is correctly replaced with mailabo-ots-ear-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT

mvn clean install -DskipTests -P wiblatt => mailabo-web-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT-wiblatt.war
where ${mailabo.ear} is correctly replaced with mailabo-wiblatt-ear-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT
```

this doesn't work:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -P ots,wiblatt
generates mailabo-web-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT-ots.war
generates mailabo-web-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT-wiblatt.war
BUT all occurrences of ${mailabo.ear} contain mailabo-wiblatt-ear-1.0.1.9-SNAPSHOT
```

what i want os for the *ots* profile to contain the ots-specific property

can this somehow be resolved? does maven have some limitation where properties with the same name can't co-exist in one build call even if they are in different profiles? could i somehow define 2 properties with different names, and 2 jboss-web.xml files using one property each, and then depending on the profile include one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up creating 2 jboss web xml files, each using a differently named property and then using the resources directive to move the web xmls into WEB-INF

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ots</id>
        <properties>
            <mailabo.ots.ear>mailabo-ots-ear-${project.version}</mailabo.ots.ear>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ots</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>ots</classifier>
                                <webResources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/module-specific/ots/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </webResources>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>wiblatt</id>
        <properties>
            <mailabo.wiblatt.ear>mailabo-wiblatt-ear-${project.version}</mailabo.wiblatt.ear>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>wiblatt</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>wiblatt</classifier>
                                <webResources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/module-specific/wiblatt/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </webResources>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enable two profiles the result gets merged, so basically the properties overlap generating only one final property.

Try executing `mvn help:effective-pom -Pots,wiblatt` to see the pom that it actually intend to execute.

I use an alternative solution to package multiple war files in one project and that is the [Iterator Plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/). You might find that helpful, too.

Comment: i have not tried this one but looks like an interesting solution, i'll keep it in mind thanks